# Which is the simplest QEMU compiling/execution setup for guest FHD resolution?

Tags: display, compiling, display-resolution, qemu

EDIT: [Hermann's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/946428/46091) of using QXL is acceptable.

I compile QEMU by myself, and run it from the commandline. This is due to having a patch applied, and to have the latest QEMU version.

The objective is to run a generic Windows (7+) guest with FHD (1920x1080) resolution, without using remote desktop (therefore, directly in the QEMU window), using an Ubuntu 16.04 x86/64 host.

When I configure the compiler with:

```
./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-debug --enable-gtk # and other parameters
```

and run QEMU with:

```
$QEMU_BINARY \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=$OVMF_20160813_BIN \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=$OVMF_20160813_VARS_TMP \
  -enable-kvm \
  -machine q35,accel=kvm,mem-merge=off \
  -cpu host \
  -vga std \
  # and other parameters
```

Windows limits the resolution to 800x600.

How can I configure/execute QEMU in order to get the expected resolution?

When I execute using `-vga vmware`, I get `Guest has not initialized the display (yet).`, which I'm not sure if it's a bug or I'm not configuring my system or QEMU properly.

It's acceptable if the solution requires installing drivers, but I'm inclined not to execute QEMU from a remote desktop connection.
If it's not possible to easily reach FHD, even a lower one is OK (anything but 800x600!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this working once, but it fell apart when I switched from Windows XP to Windows 10. Now I face the same problem, too. As far as my research went, this simply is not possible due to the unfortunate combination of OVMF EFI and Windows.

The list of resolutions available is generated in the virtual "std" graphics card BIOS. The official list of resolutions is fixed (see qemu bug 498421) but can be changed if you compile it yourself (see https://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2013/05/custom_display_resolutions_in_qemu/).

This only works with the legacy BIOS boot procedure. As soon as I use EFI boot style with OVMF, Windows chooses to rely on monitor supplied EDID exclusively. Unfortunately, qemu does not emulate a virtual monitor. Windows 10 does not receive EDID and consequently falls back to 800x600. This behaviour is **hardcoded** and cannot be changed.

In theory, you could hack Microsoft's "Basic Display Driver" as done at https://github.com/ywjheart/basic_adapter_driver_modification, but this will fail for Windows 7 or later as driver signature checks are encouraged.

Within the guest, you can manually install a monitor with the desired resolution, but Windows will still wait for EDID.

I resorted to remote desktop. Using `-vga qxl` and appropriate guest drivers is an alternative, but -
 personally - I found no advantages.

UPDATE:
[qemu v4.0.0](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/08479114b0de29f7cdd6ae20f3490b45753db083) is out (seen at [kraxel's](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2019/03/edid-support-for-qemu/)). It now generates EDID information! I compiled it with

```
./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-sdl --enable-opengl
```

, run it with

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 4 -drive if=virtio,format=raw,file=windows10 -display sdl,gl=on -device qemu-xhci,id=usb-bus -device usb-tablet -device VGA,edid=on,xres=1920,yres=1080
```

and lo and behold: Full resolution within the Windows 10 guest! The SDL UI is very responsive.

Comment: wow, thanks for taking the time! I had lost the hope :-) this is very helpful. I'll try and confirm.

Comment: Using QXL as you pointed is perfectly acceptable for my case!